# Change default record sorting for CosmosDB Gremlin API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

When I create a new Vertex in CosmosDB Gremlin API I believe there is a hidden `_ts` property that gets added to the record. This appears to be the default return order of vertices when performing a query, such as `g.V().has('orgKey', ABC)`, my results come back in ascending order (oldest first).

**Is there a way to change the default return order in CosmosDB GremlinAPI so that I get my results back newest first by default?**

I am trying to avoid a full set scan when finding the newest record matching a clause and it seems I can do that easily if I can reverse the default order in which records are returned.

Query I currently have to write:

`g.V().has('partitionKey', 1111).has('name', 'test-data').order().by('createdOn', decr).range(0, 10)`

Query I want to be able to write

`g.V().has('partitionKey', 1111).has('name', 'test-data').range(0, 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, and the return order is technically based on rid not ts, The default return order is rid, However, order by with range does not imply a scan It will only fetch the range from the backend
That does not stand in a more complex case where the ordering is not directly on the element.
If you think it is doing a full scan, connecting the execution profile may give you more insight

Comment: Great info! Is this documented somewhere? Also, what would _rid order look like for a cross-partition query - ordered first by creation or first by partition?